# Why there is a patch.dict specifically

Tags: python, pytest

I have found that the python internal deals with dictionary object different as the other object like function and list.

Does anyone have idea why python mock library (1.0.1) has a patch.dict specifically besides the existing patch and patch.object?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the first sentence. For the second, it's because there are useful things you can do in mocking a dictionary that you can't do with other things (like add key-value pairs to it).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`patch.dict()` for setting values in a dictionary just during a scope and restoring the dictionary to its original state when the test ends:

```py
foo = {'key': 'value'}
original = foo.copy()

with patch.dict(foo, {'newkey': 'newvalue'}, clear=True):
    assert foo == {'newkey': 'newvalue'}

assert foo == original
```

See the [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.dict) for further info.

Comment: note: it will reset the dict back to the original value for all keys, not just the ones you patched!